# Skeuocard in Angular app

Tags: angularjs

Did you guys have any luck setting up Skeuocard (http://kenkeiter.com/skeuocard/) in your AngularJS apps? I basically copied the example code, along with JS, installed it through bower and I am keep getting this:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Skeuocard._importImplicitOptions (http://127.0.0.1:9000/lib/skeuocard/javascripts/skeuocard.min.js:1:4226)
    at new Skeuocard (http://127.0.0.1:9000/lib/skeuocard/javascripts/skeuocard.min.js:1:1162)
    at new controller (http://127.0.0.1:9000/js/modules/OtherDirectives.js:98:32)
    at invoke (http://127.0.0.1:9000/lib/angular/angular.js:3760:17)
    at Object.instantiate (http://127.0.0.1:9000/lib/angular/angular.js:3771:23)
    at http://127.0.0.1:9000/lib/angular/angular.js:6881:28
    at http://127.0.0.1:9000/lib/angular/angular.js:6268:34
    at forEach (http://127.0.0.1:9000/lib/angular/angular.js:329:20)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://127.0.0.1:9000/lib/angular/angular.js:6255:11)
    at http://127.0.0.1:9000/lib/angular/angular.js:6529:13
```

My init code looks like this:

```
var card = new Skeuocard($("#skcard"));
```

My template:

```
<div id="skcard" class="credit-card-input no-js margin_auto">
  <p class="no-support-warning">Either you have Javascript disabled, or you're using an unsupported browser, amigo! That's why you're seeing this old-school credit card input form instead of a fancy new Skeuocard. On the other hand, at least you know it gracefully degrades...
    <label for="cc_type">Card Type</label>
    <select name="cc_type">
      <option value="">...</option>
      <option value="visa">Visa</option>
      <option value="discover">Discover</option>
      <option value="mastercard">MasterCard</option>
      <option value="maestro">Maestro</option>
      <option value="jcb">JCB</option>
      <option value="unionpay">China UnionPay</option>
      <option value="amex">American Express</option>
      <option value="dinersclubintl">Diners Club</option>
    </select>
    <label for="cc_number">Card Number</label>
    <input id="cc_number" type="text" name="cc_number" placeholder="XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX" maxlength="19" size="19"/>
    <label for="cc_exp_month">Expiration Month</label>
    <input id="cc_exp_month" type="text" name="cc_exp_month" placeholder="00"/>
    <label for="cc_exp_year">Expiration Year</label>
    <input id="cc_exp_year" type="text" name="cc_exp_year" placeholder="00"/>
    <label for="cc_name">Cardholder's Name</label>
    <input id="cc_name" type="text" name="cc_name" placeholder="John Doe"/>
    <label for="cc_cvc">Card Validation Code</label>
    <input id="cc_cvc" type="text" name="cc_cvc" placeholder="123" maxlength="3" size="3"/>
  </p>
</div>
```

Any ideas for this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 3 days of debugging, trying, and beating my head against the wall, I have fount the problem. The bloody HTML2JADE converted converted the whole thing into paragraph, that's why it wasn' working... with this code, it works:

```
<div id="skeuocard" class="credit-card-input no-js margin_auto">
  <p class="no-support-warning">Either you have Javascript disabled, or you're using an unsupported browser, amigo! That's why you're seeing this old-school credit card input form instead of a fancy new Skeuocard. On the other hand, at least you know it gracefully degrades...</p>
  <label for="cc_type">Card Type</label>
  <select name="cc_type">
    <option value="">...</option>
    <option value="visa">Visa</option>
    <option value="discover">Discover</option>
    <option value="mastercard">MasterCard</option>
    <option value="maestro">Maestro</option>
    <option value="jcb">JCB</option>
    <option value="unionpay">China UnionPay</option>
    <option value="amex">American Express</option>
    <option value="dinersclubintl">Diners Club</option>
  </select>
  <label for="cc_number">Card Number</label>
  <input id="cc_number" type="text" name="cc_number" placeholder="XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX" maxlength="19" size="19"/>
  <label for="cc_exp_month">Expiration Month</label>
  <input id="cc_exp_month" type="text" name="cc_exp_month" placeholder="00"/>
  <label for="cc_exp_year">Expiration Year</label>
  <input id="cc_exp_year" type="text" name="cc_exp_year" placeholder="00"/>
  <label for="cc_name">Cardholder's Name</label>
  <input id="cc_name" type="text" name="cc_name" placeholder="John Doe"/>
  <label for="cc_cvc">Card Validation Code</label>
  <input id="cc_cvc" type="text" name="cc_cvc" placeholder="123" maxlength="3" size="3"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Were you able to get the skeuomorphic view to data bind at all?

Comment: I've got the same issue, the plugin itself works fine but I can't get any data binding going between the values entered and my ng-model values on the controller.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue and not use jade. Any ideas?